# Automatic build with different compiler variables?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to automate the build process in install4j? 
I'd like to build 6 instances of my installer with a different compiler variable.
I know that I could change the variable in the project file (xml), but maybe there's a standard way and an option to start the build process automatically.

Thanks! Mischa

Comment: No answer needed anymore. Just realised that I could do that with media files in an amazing way. Good job to install4j, this concept is amazing